# How to fit an application onto the screen with proper size?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu server, and I've installed X and Chromium, which both start on login.

However Chromium doesn't fit on the screen properly.  I've found several fixes for people who have a window manager installed, but I would prefer not to do that if I have the option.

Comment: It _is_ the job of a window manager to manage windows. If you can install over 60 MB of Chrome, why cannot you afford 200 kB for a WM?

Answer (score 0):

See --login-screen-size at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches